# Where to get newer RHEL 7 kernel mentioned on bugzilla.redhat.com (for CentOS)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, package-management

I am using Centos 7.4 and have encountered a bug, which I found a solution for: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1502601

The problem is, solution mentions that bug is fixed in 
kernel-3.10.0-**832**.el7

and my CentOS 7.4 has kernel-3.10.0-**693** and will yum `yum update`update only to newer kernel-3.10.0-**693** version.

Is it possible to get kernel-3.10.0-**832**.el7 (or newer) without Red Hat subscription?

Answer (score 8):

You won't see this particular kernel version outside of Red Hat. It was an internal kernel build and not distributed to the public.

As you can see, this bug is not yet marked as fixed. It is clear from the comments that Red Hat is still testing it internally.

If you need this fix urgently, you'll need a Red Hat subscription and to open a support case with Red Hat. Otherwise, you can wait for the fix to be released, at which time it will also become available for CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in rhel release page https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL7 , the 3.10.0-693 is the kernel version for current rhel 7.4 release. You can also see that this release was out on 2017-07-31, which means the 7.5 should not last much now.

The 7.5 beta is out (http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/News/Red-Hat-Enterprise-Linux-7.5-Beta-Out ) and probably includes the kernel branch you need.

Comment: 7.5 Beta includes 3.10.0-830.

Comment: Indeed, just loaded it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is generally to run a current kernel (nowadays 4.15) from one of the third parties repositories such as "el-repo".

See https://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml

Basically, it's as simple as running these:

```
  rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm 
  yum install --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel kernel-ml
```

Unless you need to install very specific, redhat only, propriétary drivers, you'll be much, much better running this (much better performance, much better hardware support, much less bugs).